# MMQGIS:Create:Hub Distance: Output shapefile in wrong coordinate system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mmqgis

I have a QGIS-project that is completely in EPSG:31467 - DHDN / Gauss-Kruger zone 3. It consists of random points (camera traps) surrounded by a polygon (forest edge). I already converted the polygon into lines in order to measure the distance between each camera trap and its nearest forest edge. The tool works well apart from the problem that the output shapefile surprisingly is in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, but still displayed correctly (connecting lines between points and outline).

[image]

After then correcting the CRS of the new shapefile (WGS84) to the original project CRS (DHDN 3) the new layer ends up far away from where it should be.

[image]

Any suggestions how to get it right?

Answer (score 1):

The tool uses by default the EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 CRS. If you project is in EPSG:31467, you can see that the icon of CRS status (right down corner) is now black indicating 'enable on the fly CRS tansformation'. Save your virtual layer **temp.shp** with the correct EPSG and another name.

I tested this in my system. The **temp.shp** line (EPSG 4326) produced with the hub distance tool (MMQGIS) is the same as **line3**; but the latter was saved with EPSG 32619 of my project. After remove **temp.shp** line and deactivate 'fly CRS tansformation', **line3** remains at its position.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`correcting the CRS` might be the clue:

`Set CRS for layer` is **NOT** the right tool. Use `Save As ...` under a different name and CRS to keep the data in the right place.